# Increase unique value in few row

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, unique-constraint

I have the table create as

```
create table public.test
(
    val int unique not null
)
```

This table contains some rows

```
|   Val  |
|--------|
|1       |
|2       |
|3       |
|4       |
|5       |
|6       |
|7       |
|8       |
|9       |
```

I wanna increment all values greater then 5 (using PostgreSQL). But if try `update public.test set val=val+1 where val > 5` i will get exception:

> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_val_key"
>   DETAIL: Key (val)=(7) already exists.

How i can do this?

Comment: What exception?

Comment: @jarlh
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_val_key"
DETAIL:  Key (val)=(7) already exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need that on regular basis you should create the constraint as deferrable:

```
create table test
(
    val int not null
);
alter table test
   add constraint unique_value unique(val)
   deferrable initially immediate;
```

For the intended update to work, it's not necessary to mark the constraint as `initially deferred` or to [change the constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-constraints.html) to deferrable in the session.

With the above constraint the following update works just fine:

```
update test set val=val+1 where val > 5;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/KXI21597

Answer (score 2):

Option without `deferrable initially immediate`

```
update test t1
set val=t2.val+1
from (select val from test order by val desc) t2
where t2.val > 5 and t1.val=t2.val
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/HVZRC8695

Online example with checking that sorting is saved: http://rextester.com/FAU54991

Answer (score 1):

One option is to drop the unique constraint and then add it back.

Another option is a hack:

```
update public.test
    set val = - val
    where val > 5;

update public.test
    set val = (- val) + 1
    where val < 0;
```